# Read XML File Content from a ListBox C# win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, xml-serialization, xml-parsing

I have a `ListBox` & it has some files. I have 2 `Panels` in the same form & each `Panel` has many `Labels` which are corresponding tags of the loaded file in the `ListBox`.

Whenever the user selects each file then display the corresponding data of the selected file in the panel.

For an example this is one of the file content:

```
  <connection>
    <sourceId>sdfsdf</sourceId>
    <description>test.sdfds.interact.loop.com</description>
    <uri>https://test.sdf.interact.loop.com/WITSML/Store/Store.asmx</uri>
    <username>sdfdsf</username>
    <organizationFilter>*</organizationFilter>
    <fieldFilter>*</fieldFilter>
  </connection>
```

The listBox 1:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateListBox(listbox1, @"C:\TestLoadFiles", "*.rtld");

        }

private void PopulateListBox(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                lsb.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }
```

How can I read and display data?  Some one please explain to me how can I read/parse xml files in a directory  and display data????

Comment: Are the files xml files? How do you want the file to be displayed? You can put the data in a RichTextBox.

Comment: @Nick S.: I have edited the question and I have added the full XML file. I want to read certain content then display it in the corresponding labels. Can you help me???

Comment: Well you need the path to the file, then open the file using xmlReader: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx Then youcan go through the file and for each attribute/element check if its what you want to display for that label, then set the label text. Its going to be a little long if you have as many labels as you do xml attributes/elements

Comment: This is the path of the file `PopulateListBox(listBox1, @"C:\TestLoadFiles", "*.rtdl");`. How can I do it through the event handler of the listbox??? Please show me some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started if I understand right.

```
string path = "C:\\TestLoadFiles.xml";
string xmldoc = File.ReadAllText(path);

using (XmlReader reader = XmlRead.Create(xmldoc))
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    label_sourceId.Text = reader.GetAttribute("sourceId");
    label_description.Text = reader.GetAttribute("description");
    // ... for each label if everything will always be the same
    // might be better to read in the file, verify it, then set your labels
}
```

EDIT:
Actually a switch might be better:

```
while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
{
  switch (reader.Name)
  {
    case "description":
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value))
        label_description.Text = reader.Value;
      break;
    case "sourceId":
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value))
        label_sourceId.Text = reader.Value;
      break;
    // ...
  }
}
```

EDIT2:

So the listbox contains the file name.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string path = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    DisplayFile(path);
} 
private void DisplayFile(string path)
{
    string xmldoc = File.ReadAllText(path);

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlRead.Create(xmldoc))
    {   

        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
        {
          switch (reader.Name)
          {
            case "description":
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value))
                label_description.Text = reader.Value; // your label name
              break;
            case "sourceId":
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value))
                label_sourceId.Text = reader.Value; // your label name
              break;
            // ... continue for each label
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: loop through the files in the folder:   
`string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(folder_path);`

Comment: `private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {}` so, i'll add your code inside the listBox1??? Could you please edit your code...because when I loaded your code i got error in the xmlreader.

Comment: Does the list box contain the filepaths?

Comment: updated my answer, theres only so much I can do without more code.

Comment: XmlRead.Create(xmldoc)) this one should be 'Xmlreader.Create'. It's bizarre that when i click on the file in a list its throwing an error file not found.